# How to plot columns with different values but at the same scale with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

How to plot the two curves representing `value1` and `value2` columns according to `time` columns (x-axis) on the same graph?

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'time': [0.973841, 1.000934, 1.027918, 1.055180, 1.082246],
        'value1': [0.483, 0.494, 0.468, 0.477, 0.460]}

data2 = {'time': [0.779984, 0.801439, 0.823164, 0.844759, 0.866461],
        'value2': [0.027, 0.036, 0.030, 0.030, 0.035]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Also how to make it if one of the dataframes does not have the same length?

```py
data3 = {'time': [0.779984, 0.801439, 0.823164, 0.844759, 0.866461, 1.0, 2.0],
        'value3': [0.027, 0.036, 0.030, 0.030, 0.035, 0.04, 0.045]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot first `df` which returns an Axis object, then re-use that object. Not need to have dataframes of the same length.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ax = df1.plot(x='time')
df2.plot(x='time', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]